# X-UA-Compatible in parent is IE=8, page in IFRAME is IE=edge,chrome=1

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, x-ua-compatible

I have a add-on for a webapplication. The addon has the X-UA-Compatible set to "IE=edge,chrome=1" in order to get the JSON, DOMParser and XMLSerializer objects in javascript.

Add-on is running in a IFRAME. The problem seemes to be that the top windows with the IFRAME is using IE=8 as X-UA-Compatible and that setting seems to override the setting in the page for the addon.

Is there any way around this? Will the parent page control the X-UA-Compatible for the page in IFRAME?

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
[Trying to use IE=edge X-UA-Compatible in an iframe on a page using IE=EmulateIE7][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641511/trying-to-use-ie-edge-x-ua-compatible-in-an-iframe-on-a-page-using-ie-emulateie7

Answer (score 5):

No there is not. The view mode will always be set according to the topmost frame/window.

Comment: I can confirm this answer is correct. I've tried headers in the iframe, a meta tag and both, but nothing helped.