# How to force main page run IE11 and iFrame run IE7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-7

I have a **main application**, made with Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7 (MVC) that is forced (and must) to run with **Compatibility Mode IE11**.

Inside that application, there is a specific page with a **iFrame** that run a .Net Framework 1.1 application that **must run in Compatibility Mode IE7**.

The problem is that both (main and iframe) are running with compatibility mode IE11 and, because of that, frame application doesn't run properly.

At the moment, I've already **tried to force iframe application to run in IE7** by adding to the IIS HTTP Headers the following pair key-value:

- Custom header name:  '*X-UA-Compatible*'
- Custom header valuebox: '*IE=EmulateIE7*'

However it didn't solve my problem and i am out of ideas now.
Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should you meta tags to specify the compatibility mode (not sure if the http header do the same thing). According to this answer it should be posible:

[Main web page in standard mode, iframe in compatibility mode: any issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976213/main-web-page-in-standard-mode-iframe-in-compatibility-mode-any-issues)

Here is quite thorough documentation of what are the options:

[What does <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/what-does-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-do)

Comment: According to Microsoft, adding the tag in HTTP Headers in IIS should do the same as adding meta tag in all HTML pages.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/deviations/2009/05/07/how-to-enable-ie-8-compatibility-view-for-your-whole-web-site-or-for-specific-web-site-directories/

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723724/how-to-force-iframe-to-run-quirks-under-a-standard-parent-frame/15563464#15563464), try to use the IE browser [Quirks Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/ie_standards/ms-css21/936b2744-3e72-496d-91df-92b85e60f4d2?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

In the iframe content page, omit Doctype and add

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />`