# How to force a HTML frame content to use specific browser version?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11, html-frames

My web application was running fine till IE 10 and Firefox. I'm facing script issues while trying to use it in IE 11. My entire application comes under a frame of another HTML document whose meta header can't be changed to support specific version i.e IE 8.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" or ("EmulateIE8")>
```

I would like to force my frame alone to use IE 8 version irrespective of the parent document's browser version. When i try to use this inside my frame and check the document.documentMode() in JS, i'm getting only the parent's mode and not the IE 8 which i want the frame to be.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a question about the script issue you're facing, and solve that instead. Because sooner or later you will need to fix that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to use IE=edge X-UA-Compatible in an iframe on a page using IE=EmulateIE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641511/trying-to-use-ie-edge-x-ua-compatible-in-an-iframe-on-a-page-using-ie-emulateie7)

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not like mixing browser version. It choose the highest version if possible. If your parent using IE 11, frame using ie8 then it's will be ie11

Could you try change you doctype to html5?

```
<!doctype html>
```