# How to run IE11 page in frame of IE8 website

Tags: c#, asp.net, powerbi, internet-explorer-11, ie8-compatibility-mode

We are just starting a project that will see the merger of our currently live, IE8 asp classic site and new pieces of asp.net IE11. My current project is embedding an asp.net page into the IE8 site that loads an embedded power BI report.

Power BI requires IE11 and up to function properly. This page works fine with no issues when running on an IE 11 server. When I load this asp.net page in a frame of the asp classic site, we are getting "was blocked due to mime type mismatch" errors on a few scripts and style sheets from power bi.

The asp classic site is running in enterprise compatibility mode.

Is there a way to load the asp.net page in the frame and run it as IE11?

I have tried to add the following code to my web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
            <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
```

as well as

`<add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />`

I have also tried adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` to the top of my .cshtml view page.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible. *IE does not allow mixing IE9+ and older modes in a frame hierarchy.* For more information, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641511/trying-to-use-ie-edge-x-ua-compatible-in-an-iframe-on-a-page-using-ie-emulateie7). I also test the example in the thread and the highest document mode in the iframe I can get is IE 8.

You could also refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/jj676915(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information. As mentioned in the article:

> As of IE9 mode, webpages cannot display multiple document modes. For example, consider a standards-based webpage that contains a frame element that displays content in quirks mode. IE9 mode displays the child frame in standards mode (because the parent document is in standards mode).